# Event transitionend isn't triggered on Safari 7.0.2 & Safari 6.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transitionend

I got a problem that my product's codes bind event `transitionend` to a element. But this event isn't triggered on Chrome 33, Safari 7.0.2 & Safari 6.1. My codes can work fine on Firefox 27.0.1. My codes used to work well on Chrome's old versions like 25 and Safari's 6.0.5.

So I started to reproduce this problem. The following are reproducing codes:

```
<p>The box below combines transitions for: width, height, background-color, transform. Hover over the box to see these properties animated.</p>
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition:width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}
.box:hover {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function () {
    console.log('Transition End.');
}, false);

document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('msTransitionEnd', function () {
    console.log('Transition End.');
}, false);

document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', function () {
    console.log('Transition End.');
}, false);

document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
    console.log('Transition End.');
}, false);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPRJX

The reproducing codes can't work on Safari 7.0.2. But they can work on Chrome 33.

I wanna let my codes work on latest Chrome and Safari. From my reproducing codes, you can see `transitionend` doesn't work on Safari and work on Chrome. But on my product, it also doesn't work on Chrome.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I Suggest to try this plugin.. it uses CSS3 transitions and you can pass function to run when completed.. works in safari too.. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Sorry. I don't wanna use this plugin to fix this problem.